# Why won't Foursquare API accept 4 chars swiss zip codes?

Tags: foursquare

I'm trying to create a venue in Switzerland, which zip code is 4663. I get a 400 error saying "Invalid postal code format", although it is a valid CH zip code: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_postal_codes_of_Switzerland

So, I've checked 4sq API docs at https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/venues/add and it says nothing about zip code length or country specifics, it just says "The zip or postal code for the venue".

How should I proceed here? Should I zero fill the zip code up to X chars? How many chars should I zero fill?

Thanks!

Comment: Perhaps you should pose this question to Foursquare, they should be the ones who know. Asking questions about 3rd party APIs on Stackoverflow isn't usually very fruitful.

Comment: @deceze, I actually tried that. I went to https://developer.foursquare.com/start and clicked on Forum, and got  redirected to Stackoverflow. Would you know what would be the best way to get in touch with Foursquare guys directly?

Answer (score 0):

from all the tests I made, they don't accept postal codes bellow 5 digits, your best bet is to get in touch with them through https://twitter.com/foursquareapi as they don't seem to really have a dedicated forum.